# Pyplot contourf don't fill in "0" level

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm plotting precipitation data from weather model output. I'm contouring the data I have, using contourf. However, I don't want it to fill in the "0" level with color  (only the values >0). Is there a good way to do this? I've tried messing around with the levels.

Here's the code I'm using to plot:

```
m = Basemap(projection='stere', lon_0=centlon, lat_0=centlat,
            lat_ts=centlat, width=width, height=height)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
parallels = np.arange(0., 90, 10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[1, 0, 0, 0], fontsize=10)
meridians = np.arange(180., 360, 10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[0, 0, 0, 1], fontsize=10)

lons, lats = m.makegrid(nx, ny)
x, y = m(lons, lats)
cs = m.contourf(x, y, snowfall)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("Accumulated Snow (km/m^2)")
plt.show()
```

And here's the image I'm getting.

[image: Precipitation Plot]

An example snowfall dataset would look something like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 2 2 1 0
0 2 3 2 1 0
0 1 0 1 2 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you mock up a dataset that is similar to `snowfall`, but could be included in the question?

Comment: Sure thing, I edited the original post with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't include `0` in your `levels`, you won't plot a contour at the 0 level.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        ])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

p = ax.contourf(a, levels=np.linspace(0.5, 3.0, 11))
fig.colorbar(p)

plt.show()
```

yields:

[image]

An alternative is to mask any datapoints which are 0:

```
p = ax.contourf(np.ma.masked_array(a, mask=(a==0)),
        levels=np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 13))
fig.colorbar(p)
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I suppose its up to you which of those matches your desired plot the most.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using 'locator' with MaxNLocator('prune = 'lower') from the ticker subclass. See [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

p = ax.contourf(a, locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'))
fig.colorbar(p)

plt.show()
```

[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEmBN.png)

The 'nbins' parameter can be used to control the number of intervals (levels)

```
p = ax.contourf(a, locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(prune = 'lower'), nbins = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure things out myself, there are two ways I found of solving this problem.

1. Mask out all data <0.01 from the data set using

   ```
   np.ma.masked_less(snowfall, 0.01)
   ```

   or
2. Set the levels of the plot to be from 0.01 -> whatever maximum value

   ```
   levels = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)
   ```

   then

   ```
   cs = m.contourf(x, y, snowfall, levels)
   ```

I found that option 1 worked best for me.